Black artifacting on cycles render with sub-surafce scattering enabled, merge by distance not working

In this image there is some black artifacting from cycles, which I thought was caused by z-fighting, but I've noticed it almost entirely vanishes when I disable sub-surface scattering, however merge by distance doesn't solve the issue and I'm not sure how to proceed, in the other image it shows the topology of one of the artifacting areas. could someone please advise


Check if you have duplicated vertices (select all A and merge M by distance in edit mode). Also do a face orientation check.

The screenshot of the mesh looks as if there was intersecting geometry, but not exactly duplicated... so Merge by Distance will probably not help because the vertices are too far away from each other and also build faces which are oriented completely to others in that area... seems to me as if you would have to clean up the mesh manually. But I cannot really see what is goung on there...
